# oracle, how to use outer table column in joined subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

give tables below i need to get all record from `NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_LOC_008` and for each row get from `NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_007` with

```
AuditData <= NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_LOC_008.AuditData
and ID_ELEMENTO_008 = ID_007
```

using join cannot do it since code will be that and inner condition is not allowed

```
select * from 

NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_LOC_008
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_007
  WHERE 
    NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_007.AuditData <= NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_LOC_008.AuditData 
    AND ID_007 = ID_ELEMENTO_008
  ORDER BY NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_007."AuditData" DESC
  fetch next 1 rows only)
ON ID_007 = ID_ELEMENTO_008
```

with subquery in select i'm forced to select one column only

is there a sql standard way to do it without messing up with object or record for that simple requirement?

tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_LOC_008" 
   (    "AuditId" NUMBER(9,0),
    "AuditAction" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE) ,
    "AuditUser" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE) ,
    "AuditData" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "ID_008" NUMBER(12,0), 
    "ID_LINGUA_008" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "ID_ELEMENTO_008" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "NOTE_008" VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE "NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_007" 
(   "AuditId" NUMBER(9,0) ,
    "AuditAction" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE) ,
    "AuditUser" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
    "AuditData" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "ID_007" NUMBER(12,0), 
    "ID_STATO_ORIGINE_007" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "ID_STATO_DESTINAZIONE_007" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "NOTA_OBBLIGATORIA_007" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "ALLEGATO_OBBLIGATORIO_007" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "FINALE_007" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "ID_WORKFLOW_007" NUMBER(9,1)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_LOC_008 n8
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT *
         FROM   NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_007 n7
         WHERE  n7."AuditData" <= n8."AuditData"
         AND    n7.ID_007      =  n8.ID_ELEMENTO_008
         ORDER BY n7."AuditData" DESC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       )
```

or, in earlier versions, use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT n7.*,
         n8.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY n7.ID_007
           ORDER     BY n7."AuditData" DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_LOC_008 n8
         INNER JOIN NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_007 n7
         ON     n7."AuditData" <= n8."AuditData"
            AND n7.ID_007      =  n8.ID_ELEMENTO_008
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_LOC_008 n8
INNER JOIN NAT_DASH_AUD_ELEMENTO_WORKFLOW_007 n7
ON n7.ID_007 = n8.ID_ELEMENTO_008
    AND n7.AuditData <= n8.AuditData
ORDER BY n7.ID_007, n7.AuditData DESC, n8.AuditData;  --ORDER BY...
```